# I am not able to use gulp with react 18 to make all inclusive index.html, Uncaught Error: Minified React error #299

Tags: reactjs, gulp

I was a happy user of react and gulp until react 18 was published. I created react app and used gulp to collect all build files content into index.html. As I said it works fine with react versions prior to 18. The error I see in developers console is:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #299; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=299 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at n.createRoot ((index):6144:55)
    at (index):6952:27
    at (index):6953:23
    at (index):6954:15
```

Steps to reproduce, credits to [Coding Shiksha](https://codingshiksha.com/tutorials/gulp-js-tutorial-to-bundle-all-cssjs-files-inside-react-js-app-into-a-single-html-file-for-production/):

1. `npx create-react-app sampleapp`
2. `cd sampleapp`
3. `npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-inline-source gulp-replace`
4. `Ceate a .env file inside the root folder and copy paste the below code`

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

5. `create a gulpfile.js inside the root directory and copy paste the following code`

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const inlinesource = require('gulp-inline-source');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('default', () => {
  return gulp
    .src('./build/*.html')
    .pipe(replace('.js"></script>', '.js" inline></script>'))
    .pipe(replace('rel="stylesheet">', 'rel="stylesheet" inline>'))
    .pipe(
      inlinesource({
        compress: false,
        ignore: ['png'],
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

6. `npm run build`
7. `npx gulp`
8. `npm install -g serve`
9. `serve -s build`
10. open browser at http://localhost:3000, open dev console and observe the error

The formatted (unminified) `index.html` is published [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSVVOsfBNvTJWqTzTL8x4054apL2w-2FLQzAcb0Z7ZgYmagrSEn9huxqwIXrbXGjCzmZaNmXiYMa3wl/pub).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve this by wrapping root.render in an onload listener:

index.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
});
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much @todd-krupa. Just to clarify that this change needs to be done in the `index.js` file.